# Looping through DISTINCT rows

Tags: php, sql

I have this table for a web panel that I'm making:

[image]

On a particular page, the latest archive for each server is shown, which means it has to look at distinct server IDs and sort them by a descending time stamp as shown.

[image]

At the moment I'm having to run `SELECT DISTINCT server_id FROM archives ORDER BY time DESC` but this means I have to use `foreach` in PHP to run an additional query to get the rest of the fields for the archive (`id, job_id, time, sha1_sum, file_name, size`).

Is there a single SQL statement that can get the latest archive of each `server_id` sorted by `time` descending? Doing it all in one query would be much easier and cleaner code-wise.

**EDIT:** I should note that the list of results in the web table are wrong, as the result from 15/06/2013 is displayed at the top when the archive directly below is more recent.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) and [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group.html) in combination.

```
SELECT server_id,MAX(time), id, job_id, time, sha1_sum, file_name, size FROM archives GROUP BY server_id
```

Comment: Running that returns the first two rows in that table which I don't understand. It should be selecting the 3rd row for the server with ID 1 because it is more recent than the 1st row?

Answer (score 0):

This is yet another variation of the ["max in group" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=max%20in%20group%20sql), by far the most common problem SQL newbies seem to have.

One way to solve it is with a [correlated subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html) to identify all archives that have the maximum time in their respective group.

```
SELECT
  a.server_id,
  a.id, a.job_id, a.time, a.sha1_sum, a.file_name, a.size
FROM 
  archives a
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM archives 
    WHERE server_id = a.server_id AND time > a.time
  )
ORDER BY 
  time DESC
```

Index `(server_id, time)` and do a GROUP BY on the outer query if you expect some archives for the same `server_id` to have the same `time` value.